# ECDSA secp256k1 offline signer for blockchain in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am doing currently doing blockcypher api ([https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/#creating-transactions](http://Blockcypher%20api)) integration and I got blocked at one point.
I am dealing with transactions I have created transaction but stucked in sigining part.
Problem:
When I am creating transaction I am getting key(32b5ea64c253b6b466366647458cfd60de9cd29d7dc542293aa0b8b7300cd827  (sample)). Which is suppoed to be signed 
with private key.So I have private key. Currently api is using GoLang signer which I don't want/can't use. I have been looking for simple offline signer as the document explains (ECDSA secp256k1 signing tool should work).

So I am looking for a simple method say for example

```
string sign(string hash,string pvtkey)
```

I have had a look QbitNinja, BouncyCastle, Nentherium but none of them fullfills my requirement or I am not able of making proper use.

If any one have the simple implementation of above formation please do share.

**Targeted framework .net45**.

My Needs equivalent implemenatation in GoLang
 https://github.com/blockcypher/btcutils/tree/master/signer

Comment: Equivalent implementation in GoLang https://github.com/blockcypher/btcutils/tree/master/signer

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to share with you a code sample, but you can draw inspiration from http://mytenpennies.wikidot.com/blog:using-bouncy-castle and also look at the Ethereum go lang test cases to verify your results.